# Entity Framework user accounts - change schema

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've created a new MVC project and set authentication to Individual User Accounts.  When I run the application it automatically creates tables to support these under the 'dbo' schema.  Is it possible to change this to another?

I've tried adding the commented lines below but this didn't work - got a bunch of errors about keys not being defined:-

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("App1", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        //These are the lines I added - didn't work as expected.
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("MAIN");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("schemaName")` for Entity Framework 6 and above.

The errors you are getting its cause of `IdentityDbContext` already overriding the `OnModelCreating` of `DbContext` and configuring keys for Identity Entities (IdentityUser, IdentityRole etc).
You need to call the base method like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("MAIN");

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    // changes for identity entities here
}
```